# PySpark ML: OnevsRest strategy for LinearSVC

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, svm, apache-spark-ml

I am a newbie in PySpark . I installed Spark 2.3.0 on Windows 10 .
I want to use Linear SVM classifier for training with cross validation but for a dataset that has 3 classes . So I am trying to apply One vs Rest strategy from Spark ML. But it appears that there is something wrong in my code because I got an error showing that LinearSVC is for binary classification.

here is the error that occurs when I try to execute "crossval.fit" line while debugging:

```
 pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: LinearSVC only supports binary classification. 1 classes detected in LinearSVC_43a48b0b70d59a8cbdb1__labelCol'
```

Here is my code:
( I am trying on a very small dataset of 10 instances only)

```
        from pyspark import SparkContext
        sc = SparkContext('local', 'my app')
        from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
        from pyspark import SQLContext
        sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
        import numpy as np

        x_train=np.array([[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[9,10,11],[2,4,5],[2,7,9],[3,7,6],[8,3,6],[5,8,2],[44,11,55],[77,33,22]])
        y_train=[1,0,2,1,0,2,1,0,2,1]  
        #converting numpy array to dataframe          
        df_list = []
        i = 0           
        for element in x_train:  # row
            tup = (y_train[i], Vectors.dense(element))
            i = i + 1
            df_list.append(tup)

        Train_sparkframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_list, schema=['label', 'features'])

        from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
        from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
        from pyspark.ml.classification import OneVsRest
        from pyspark.ml.classification import LinearSVC

        LSVC = LinearSVC()
        ovr = OneVsRest(classifier=LSVC)
        paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(LSVC.maxIter, [10, 100]).addGrid(LSVC.regParam,
                                                                                      [0.001, 0.01, 1.0,10.0]).build()

        crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=ovr,
                                  estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                                  evaluator=MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="f1"),
                                  numFolds=2) 
        cvModel = crossval.fit(Train_sparkframe)
        bestModel = cvModel.bestModel
```

Comment: This should not be an issue now. The `OneVsRest` class should also support `LinearSVC` now. Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.OneVsRest) says:

> Note Only LogisticRegression and NaiveBayes are supported now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your code effectively to the letter without issue in a Python 3.5/Spark 2.3 hosted environment in this IBM notebook: https://eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/24bb87d9-d28b-433b-b85a-5a86f4d0b56b/view?access_token=3c7bec3ed89bb518357fcce8005874a66a1d65833e997603141632b5cbb484db

Since the cloud env manages Spark context for you, I'd suggest you look into your Spark setup and double-check your column naming.